# Why does Oppenheimer appear naked in this scene?

Tags: character, analysis, oppenheimer

Oppenheimer is being cross-examined
and suddenly there's a noticeable change in his attire, transitioning from being naked to wearing a coat and back again.

[image]

This shift seems abrupt and potentially symbolic. What is the context or significance of this scene? Was it intended to convey a specific message or theme within the film?

Comment: Have you got a YT clip or a timestamp?

Comment: Just added a picture. @Tetsujin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene is not real. It is being imagined by his wife (who is sitting on the coach behind).

She is imagining it because he is answering questions about his one-off encounter with Jean Tatlock during his ongoing marriage. In other cuts his wife is also imagining Tatlock sitting on top of him naked and doing him.

The significance of the scene is to illustrate the pain his loving wife has to go through with this proceeding — even though he had told her about that encounter with Tatlock before.

It is also to illustrate what kind of assholes the questioning lawyer (Roger Robb) and his puppet master Lewis Strauss were in pushing those barely relevant questions to cause pain and distress.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/oppenheimer-2023.pdf), Robert Oppenheimer is being forced to discuss the details of his sordid affair in front of his loving wife, whom he betrayed.

He describes himself as 'naked' (metaphorically speaking) in front of the commission and his wife. His wife also sees him as literally naked, imagining him with his mistress.

> INT. ROOM 2022, ATOMIC ENERGY COMMISSION -- DAY
> I sit at the table, self-conscious, testifying...
>
> **OPPENHEIMER:** *She had indicated a great desire to see me before we left. At that time I couldn’t. But I felt that she had to see me...*
>
> Kitty watches me testify. I am NAKED...
>
> **OPPENHEIMER(CONT’D):** *She was undergoing psychiatric treatment. She was extremely unhappy.*
>
> **ROBB:** *Did you find out why she had to see you?*
>
> **OPPENHEIMER:** *Because she was still in love with me.*
>
> Kitty watches Tatlock, also naked, STRADDLE me, head on my shoulder, facing Kitty...
>
> **ROBB:** *You spent the night with her didn’t you?*
>
> As Tatlock GRINDS on me she locks eyes with Kitty...
>
> **OPPENHEIMER:** *Yes.*

This is one of the events that his lawyer had warned him would happen if he didn't accept his dismissal without complaint.